# I want to do a mathematical operation with my two inputs

Tags: java, android, string, double

```
EditText txtDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
    display = txtDisplay.getText().toString();
    operator = display.split("\\d|\\.");
    operand = display.split("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/");

    if(operator[0] == "+"){
        answer = Double.valueOf(operand[0]) + Double.valueOf(operand[1]);
    }

    if(operator[0] == "-"){
        answer = Double.valueOf(operand[0]) - Double.valueOf(operand[1]);
    }

    if(operator[0] == "*"){
        answer = Double.valueOf(operand[0]) * Double.valueOf(operand[1]);
    }

    if(operator[0] == "/"){
        answer = Double.valueOf(operand[0]) / Double.valueOf(operand[1]);
    }

    txtDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
```

The displayed answers is always 0.0 and I don't know what I did wrong. Is it my conversion of data types?

Comment: Have you debugged the code? I guess that no `if` is entered.

Comment: you should `Log.i` the contents of `operator` and `operand` before all

Comment: use sqlite to get result directly in one line. Just pass the expression written in edittext. and get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `equals()` method to compare Strings identity. not `==` operator.

```
if(operator[0].equals("+")) {
    answer = Double.valueOf(operand[0]) + Double.valueOf(operand[1]);
}
```